# Convert a List<List<string>> to string[]

Tags: java, arrays, string, list

whats the shortest way to convert a `<List<List<string>>` to a string-array?

I tried with a `foreach` loop, but in this case I don't have an index for my array, so I can't fill up the array!? :-(

```
        foreach (List<string> list in myList)
        {
            foreach (string s in list)
            {
                Array[s] = list.ToArray;
            }
        }
```

Comment: What's wrong with counting along yourself?

Comment: Use a for loop instead of foreach

Comment: Do you needs an Array of Strings or an Array of List of Strings ?

Comment: And why do you have String in lowercase like "string", and what is Array[s] - does 'Array' pretend to be a variable name?

Comment: The point is, there is no ``foreach`` keyword in Java. The code looks more C# to me.

Comment: But it's tagged "Java" :\

Comment: posted code snippet isn't in java. please use right tags.

Answer (score 1):

First you need to know how big the array needs to be (this is because Arrays in Java can't be dynamic; can't change their size dynamically):

```
int max = 0;
for(List<String> list : myList)
{
   max += list.size();
}
String[] array = new String[max];
```

Then use your foreach loop (please note, it has different syntax) with an additional variable to keep current index:

```
int i = 0;
for(List<string> list : myList)
{
    for(String s : list)
    {
        array[i++] = s;
    }
}
```

Please also note how `String` is spelled.

Comment: There is no such thing like `foreach` in Java.

Answer (score 1):

First, calculate the size of the `String[]` array.

```
int size = 0;
for(List list : myList)
{
   size += list.size();
}
String[] array = new String[size];
```

Then, fulfill the array with all the strings in each of the lists:

```
int i = 0;
for (List<String> list : myList) {
    for (String s : list) {
        array[i++] = s;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `for(int i=0; i<myList.size(); i++){ ... }`

Answer (score 0):

you can use something like this :

```
int i=0;
foreach (List<string> list in myList)
        {
            foreach (string s in list)
            {
                Array[i] = s;
                i++;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
List<List<String>> lisfOfList = new ArrayList<List<String>>();

List<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();
for(List<String> list : lisfOfList){
    result.addAll(list);
}

String[] s = result.toArray(new String[result.size()]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this,

> List<String> list1 = new ArrayList<String>();
>
> list1.add("aa");
>
> list1.add("bb");
>
> List<String> list2 = new ArrayList<String>();
>
> list2.add("cc");
>
> list2.add("dd");
>
> list2.add("ee");
>
> List<List<String>> arrL = new
>   ArrayList<List<String>>();
>
> arrL.add(list1);
>
> arrL.add(list2);
>
> List<String> strList = new ArrayList<String>();
>
> for (List<String> list : arrL)
>
> {     strList.addAll(list); }
>
> String []strArray = new String[strList.size()];
>
> strList.toArray(strArray);
>
> for (String string : strArray)
>
> {     System.out.println(string); }